# Passing UINavigationBar to multiple UIViewControllers

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

So, at the moment, I am attempting to pass the same `UINavigationBar` to multiple `UIViewController`s.

For example, say I have a `UINavigationController` whose view is a `UIViewController`'s `UIView`. Withinn the custom `UIViewController`'s `UIView` I modify the contents of the UINavigationBar's `titleview`.

```
UIView *titleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.origin.x + 50, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.origin.y, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.width - 100, 44)];
UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button1.frame = CGRectMake(35, titleView.frame.origin.y + 2, 40, 40);
[button1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"FacebookFriendRequestIcon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(FriendRequestsPopover:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[titleView addSubview:button1];
UIButton *button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button2.frame = CGRectMake(80, titleView.frame.origin.y + 2, 40, 40);
[button2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"FacebookMessagesIcon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(MessagesPopover:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[titleView addSubview:button2];
UIButton *button3 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button3.frame = CGRectMake(125, titleView.frame.origin.y + 2, 40, 40);
[button3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"FacebookNotificationsIcon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button3 addTarget:self action:@selector(NotificationsPopover:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[titleView addSubview:button3];

self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView;
```

When a user presses a button within the UIViewcontroller (not referring to the navigationBar's items), the user is then pushed to another `UIViewController`:

```
GeneralInfoViewController *generalInformationController = [[GeneralInfoViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:generalInformationController animated:YES];
```

`UIViewController1(UINavigationController) pushes to UIViewController2(UINavigationController)`

So, the `generalInformationController` is subclassed as a `UIViewController`. Now when the push occurs, I would like an animation to occur, but only with the `UIView`'s not with the NavigationBar.

An example application would be like Facebook, the Navigationbar's middle buttons (messages, friend requests, and notifications) are ALWAYS visibile and never animate away when a viewcontroller is pushed onto the stack.

Anyone have any ideas on how this is done? I guess a theoretical answer would be nice but a coding example would be nicer :)

Answer (score 0):

> An example application would be like Facebook, the Navigationbar's
>   middle buttons (messages, friend requests, and notifications) are
>   ALWAYS visibile and never animate away when a viewcontroller is pushed
>   onto the stack.

That might be a clue that the Facebook app doesn't use a navigation controller. I don't know if it does or doesn't, but it would probably be easier to write your own container view controller that does what you want than to try to force UINavigationController to behave in a way that it's not designed to.

Answer (score 0):

If you use navigation controller for pushing and poping, you can't make, that your nag bar stay on his place;
BUT you can try it:

```
newView.bounds = mainView.bounds; //newView can be nextViewController.view
newView.biunds.size.height=newView.biunds.size.height-self.navBar.bounds.size.height; //devide navBar height
newView.frame = CGRectMake(newView.frame.origin.x + 784, newView.frame.origin.y, newView.frame.size.width, newView.frame.size.height);
[mainView addSubview:newView];

/* Begin transition */
[UIView beginAnimations:@"Slide Left" context:oldView];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDelay:0.0f];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5f];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(slideInCompleted:finished:context:)];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
newView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, newView.frame.size.width, newView.frame.size.height);
oldView.frame = CGRectMake(oldView.frame.origin.x - 784, oldView.frame.origin.y, oldView.frame.size.width, oldView.frame.size.height);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Post comments, for your result.